# Reading Sql query stored in CSV file in python is not working

Tags: python-3.x

```
        import cx_Oracle
        from datetime import datetime


        #reading query from file 

    f = open('C:/Users/pubhatia/Documents/learning/python/query/test.sql')
    #print(f.read())
    filer = f.read()
    print(filer)

    print(repr(filer))
    f.close()
    #filer3=filer

    filer=filer.replace("\'","")


    #print( repr(filer3 )       
    filer2="select * from dual"

    if filer==filer2:
     print('same value')
    else:
     print ('no same ')

    #create connection string
    conn_str = u'user/pwd@db'
    #setting up connection 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)  
    c = conn.cursor()
    #c.execute("select WORK_PHONE,source_sys_cd,source_sys_id  from mdm_people_standard where source_sys_cd ='%s' AND  WORK_PHONE IS NOT NULL"%(source_name))
    c.execute(filer2)
    start_time = datetime.now()
    for row in c:
        print( row)
    conn.close()
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

I am unable to run sql query stored in text file because it is giving me an error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "oracle_test.py", line 18, in 
    c.execute(filer)
    cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
So just to check what is stored in filer I found 
filer value  is ' "select * from dual" '
and that is why I am unable to run query 

Now I am unable to remove it as this string. 
Please help 


test.sql is storing simple select statement 

"select * from dual"
```

Answer (score 0):

There was mistake in my text file where I am storing SQL query .

I was storing it in below format
"select * from dual "
pressed Enter

But it needs to be stored in below format

select * from dual 
then press nothing